# Am experiencing issues with email delivery-"response code 250 but got code '550' "

Tags: laravel-5, swiftmailer, exim

I am using Exim mail server for my smtp and experiencing an issue when sending emails from the server if the connection is instantiated from within the server. However if I try authenticating from outside, emails are sent without any problems. Am using Laravel which ships with Swift mailer. This is the error laravel is giving out.

```
production.ERROR: Expected response code 250 but got code "550", with message "550 127.0.0.1 is _my_ address
```

Exim's log also has a similar error;

```
H=localhost [127.0.0.1] X=TLSv1:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:256 CV=no rejected MAIL <no-reply@mydomain.com>: 127.0.0.1 is _my_ address
```

My .env file has credentials set up correctly as follows

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mydomain.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=no-reply@mydomain.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

The code used to send the emails is as below;

```
Mail::to('admin@mydomain.com')->send(new AlertEmail($information));
```

What am wondering is,could the problem be caused by trying to send the email to addresses within the same domain? I hope someone can help me out. Am almost going crazy.

**NB: Roundcube is sending emails fine.**

Comment: what is the `from` address?

Comment: The default one obtained from the .env file, i.e no-reply@mydomain.com

Comment: then what is the `from` address when you send from `Roundcube`

Comment: It shows no-reply@mydomain.com. The correct origin of the email.

Comment: so `MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS` is `no-reply@mydomain.com`?

Comment: Yes it is. I am really wondering what could be the problem